# Using streams to convert objects to strings

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, stringstream

I have an object that overrides the stream operator << to act as a stringstream to make console printing easy.

```
cout << obj << endl;
```

I want to test this functionality in a unit test by comparing the string output with an expected string. I currently accomplish this by:

```
stringStream ss;
ss << obj;
string objStr = ss.str();

EXPECT_EQ(objStr, "expected string output");
```

This is not particular readable and it is certainly not succinct. Is there any easier, shorter and simpler way to get the string representation of an obj?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a small, generic utility function that does that thing for you:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
std::string make_string(T const& o)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << o;
    return ss.str();
}
```

And use it this way:

```
EXPECTED_EQ(make_string(obj), "expected string output");
```

Comment: My c++ isn't great. Would the result of ss.str() be allocated on the stack of make_string() or allocated on the stack of the function that calls make_string()?

Comment: Also is std:forward<T>(o) necessary, can't you just do ss << o?

Comment: @EthanHeilman: `str()` returns an `std::string` by value, you don't need to worry about its life time. `std::forward<T>(o)` is not necessary in this case, it's just a usage of perfect-forwarding which *in this case* is equivalent to `ss << o`. I just got used to write `std::forward<T>`. I will edit the answer